# Remove Multiple occurance values from map or arraylist

Tags: java

```
("A", "1");    ("B", "2");    ("C", "2");    ("D", "3");    ("E", "3");
```

I have a map with duplicate values like above

I would like to the map to have

```
("A", "1");
```

And in case of list

if list contains `{1,2,2,3,3,4,5}`

i want `{1,4,5}`

Comment: I don't see how those values are duplicated for your map.. but you could use a [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) for your list of values.

Comment: The keys are unique the values don't have to. Why not set the values as keys and vice versa? Or should the, now, keys also be unique?

Comment: Could you clarify just what you are after? Looks like you want to remove any duplicates completely, including the original. Are you just trying to keep the unique values?

Comment: @danielson if we do so i hope  (a,1),(b,2),(d,3) will come as result

Comment: @ modred U got r8 . i just want to remove any duplicates completely as i mentioned in my question

Comment: I don't want to nitpick, but your title is a bit incorrect. You don't want to remove duplicate values, you want to remove ALL values that appear more than once. This is why Gosu's nor Danielson's suggestions will not work.

Removing duplicates implied leaving the original value. That is not the case here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a Java 7 solution for the ArrayList case:

```
Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
for (String elem : list) {
    Integer count = counts.get(elem);
    if (count == null) {
        counts.put(elem, 1);
    } else {
        counts.put(elem, count + 1);
    }
}

Iterator<String> it = list.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    int count = counts.get(it.next());
    if (count > 1) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

Note that this is not efficient.  In the worst-case it is `O(N^2)`, because `it.remove()` is an `O(N)` operation for an `ArrayList`.

However, it should be sufficient to understand the basic approach that needs to be taken.  (Tagir's Java 8 solutions are doing roughly the same thing as this code ... except that they are building lists and taking list lengths instead of counting.)

Comment: Thank u very much stephen. can u please give me solution for map also

Comment: You can generalize from the ArrayList solution to the Map solution.  Try it yourself.  It will be good for your programming ability :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's Java-8 solution for both tasks:

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> noDups(Map<K, V> input) {
    Map<V, List<Entry<K, V>>> counts = input.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(Entry::getValue));
    return counts
            .values().stream().filter(list -> list.size() == 1)
            .collect(toMap(list -> list.get(0).getKey(), list -> list.get(0).getValue()));
}

public static <T> List<T> noDups(Collection<T> input) {
    LinkedHashMap<T, Long> counts = input.stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), LinkedHashMap::new, counting()));
    return counts
            .entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue() == 1l)
            .map(Entry::getKey).collect(toList());
}
```

Comment: Hi Tagir, is it only possible in java-8 or in previous version also possible

Comment: hi Tagir, i m beginner to java. if u can help me on programing simple code as i have [f, l,a, p,a,f] list and i want my list as [l,p] . bcz i dont understand what is new, counting() and collect(toList())